# map in class gives compile error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to define a class

```
class BTree
{
private:
     map<std::string,BTree*> *node;
public:

    BTree(void);
    ~BTree(void);
    void Insert(BTree *);
};
```

on compiling the code the compiler gives me an error

```
error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration  
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  
error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration
```

I have tried to change the map to something simple like `map<int,int> node` it still gives me the same error. Am I missing something ?

Comment: `typename cannot be used outside a template declaration`... uhm.. there is no typename in the code, are you sure you are providing the code and the error together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely because you don't have the `std` namespace listed in a `using`.  The type `map` isn't in the global namespace so  so `map` isn't resolvable.  Try the following

```
class BTree {
private:
  std::map<std::string, BTree*> *node;

  ...
};
```

Comment: I have to wait 11 minutes to mark your answer as accepted , which i will spend by beating my head against a wall :/ . thanks